# Regex for every occurrence of a Pattern, which extracts entire text string between = and \s

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a program which will reformat an XML file.

e.g.; The following is the XML snippet.

```
<ServiceRequest actionCode=KK
          addedWithoutItinerary=false airlineCode=1S
          code=ADTK orderNumber=1 serviceCount=1
          serviceType=SSR ssrType=AFX>
```

I want to surround all attribute values with double quotes.

e.g.;

```
<ServiceRequest actionCode="KK"
              addedWithoutItinerary="false" airlineCode="1S"
              code="ADTK" orderNumber="1" serviceCount="1"
              serviceType="SSR" ssrType="AFX">
```

Hence, I am trying to write a REGEX Pattern which can serve the purpose.

I want to extract all text strings between = and single whitespace character ("\s"), like
"=false ", "=1S " and so on.

I tried this Pattern

```
private static final Pattern ATTR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<==)(.*)(?= |\\n)");
```

but this Pattern is grouping all texts which has ending character as whitespace.

e.g.;

```
KK
          addedWithoutItinerary=false airlineCode=1S
          code=ADTK orderNumber=1 serviceCount=1
          serviceType=SSR
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use a XML parser instead of regex

Comment: This XML contains lots of BOM characters and lots of unnecessary strings which generated from LOGS. Parser won't help much here.

Comment: Linked question does not appear to be dupe as it deals wit a single attribute `location` only not a generic solution as OP is seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
=([^\s"<>]+)
```

And replace using `="$1"`

[RegEx Demo](http://regexr.com/5go10)

**Java Code:**

```
String repl = xml.replaceAll("=([^\\s\"<>]+)", "=\"$1\"");
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `=`: Match a `=`
- `([^\s"<>]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not whitespace, `"`, `<` and `>'` and capture that in group #1
- `="$1"` is replacement part that puts `=` and capture value in double quotes.

Comment: But this will extract the exact word without = sign. Please suggest if I am wrong here.

(?<==)([^\s"<>]+)

Link: https://regexr.com/5go7f

Comment: Yes a lookbehind will also work as you are suggesting

Comment: Hi @anubhava can you please suggest how to read the value of $1?

e.g.; 

if("$1".equals("some value")) {

    //Do something...
}

Comment: If you want value of `$1` separately then you will need to use `Pattern and Matcher` and then use `matcher.group(1)`. You can check sample Java code in the regex101 link I posted in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I know. I was thinking is there a way to read the value directly from the metacharacter. Thanks for clarifying.